# How to use standalone JBoss Transactions with Spring, Hibernate and JPA?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jboss, jta

I have an app that is deployed on Tomcat but I need to use JTA because I am connecting to multiple data sources. I don't want to use JBoss AS but would like to use the JBoss transaction manager. I currently have my app configured to use Bitronix but my boss wants me to use something more popular. Sigh.

Does anyone know how to use the JBoss transaction manager with Spring and Hibernate but not use JBoss AS?

Comment: You really should convince your boss that Bitronix is a perfect choice in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUseJBossJTAStandaloneTransactionManager ?

If it's not already supported in Spring, writing your custom `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` to wrap JBoss TM shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @John Adding more info to this answer.Use tomcat jdbc pooling to make XA connection pooling work,check  http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html. From my experience none of the connection pooling libraries other than this behaves well for XA Connections. I can empathize with you because I was in similar situation an year back.